# Is it better to create elements or just have them ready on html?

Tags: javascript, html

I see a lot of people in here giving answers that requires you to create a new element in the html page through Javascript using "document.createElement" and other methods. I can understand this to a certain extent, but is it really always necessary?

For example, when I build my own nonprofessional pages, they always require user input. As their input is being done, there are locations in the html file that displays the results based on whatever was typed by the user. I make all the tags beforehand in the html file, so all I need to do is simply apply the javascript results to the specific id in the html. However, as mentioned already, apparently a lot of people like to create the elements within the Javascript itself and send it to the html through document.createElement or using variables like `var group = $('<div class="group"></div>');` and etc. Am I doing a bad habit and this is really the best way to do it?

Let's suppose I need to make a list that displays info based on what the user typed in. What I do is have the list ready and done in the html with no display, ready to be shown only after the time is ready, instead of coding stuff like:

```
var list = $('<ul class="legend"></ul>');

var listItem = $('<li><span class="example' + i + '"></span>' + this
+ '</li>').appendTo(list); //in a loop, etc.
```

I can understand sometimes having to create stuff out of the js, but personally I prefer having everything set and done at html just waiting to be used, and I wonder if this is a bad thing.
Thanks in advance for the answers.

**Edit:** Thanks a lot for the answers, I really appreciate. I'd like to put another example here, although I think the idea itself is already clear as is. I understand the need of having to update the page's content dynamically depending on the situation, but what I really had in mind was: On a situation where the table/list/whatever is going to be displayed in a preestablished way where nothing will be added or subtracted, is there any need to use the above method? For example, I find it a lot easier to type this in the html:

```
<input type='button' onclick='display(2)' value='Click me'>
```

than this in js:

```
var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
inputElement.type = 'button';
inputElement.value = 'Click me';
inputElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
    display(2);
});

document.body.appendChild(inputElement);
```

Both of these do pretty much the same thing, with the exception the first is already inserted in the html, while the second is created through js. The main question that is being asked here is: In a situation where everything is already predetermined and there's nothing the user can do to change how the page will be displayed, is there **any** reason of why I should do the js method in the example above, instead of the html one?

Comment: It's not always possible to have all the html written. Some applications are dynamic enough that you cannot know beforehand exactly what html you will need.

Comment: Imagine you're making a todo list. One `<li>` for every item in the list. You can't exactly create all possible `<li>`s from the beginning, right? Sometimes you have to generate new elements.

Comment: @Mike C So would this only be useful when I don't know the amount of times it'll need to be displayed? I can comprehend that. However, a lot of answers use these methods despite of anything.

Comment: Try to use a templating system like underscore, handlebars, mustache, etc... And it would be helpful to learn a MVC framework library just as Backbone/Mariontette or for more complex apps Angular.

Comment: It depends on situation. Consider a case a web app will show the payment plan of your credit according to some inputs which you've a relative freedom to choose. And they want to show this in a table. Every change made by yourself will add or delete a row from that table. I can create a fiddle if you want to see it live.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time for a dynamic webapp, you *can't* really have everything already included in the page, for example, a list of contents that is requested through AJAX.

Indeed, the `<ul>` tag can be put in manually beforehand, but what about the `<li>` inside? What if you don't always want a list there, and you have multiple type of data that can be displayed? Dynamically injecting elements makes the page flexible.

With large scale frameworks you can even have an empty body, which its content is dynamically created from several HTML templates on the go.

My advise is that, it might be fine to have all the elements set up and ready go for a small page, but for something more dynamic you should use [a framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) to help you in handling the content.

Answer (score 2):

I personally try to always build html template (styling something built by js is nightmare) with style="display: none" to prevent flashing (before jQuery kicks in).

Then on document ready I save those templates to variables (removing from DOM and removing hiding style as no longer required):

```
var $element = $('element').detach().show();
```

Now can use `$element` to whatever need (clone it in loops, or manipulate directly if only one required).

NOTE: Making unstyled single elements without any attributes like plain `<li>` doesn't make sens that way.

Comment: This is exactly what I usually do.

Comment: No need of inline styles. You can set `display: none` in a stylesheet in the head.

Comment: @Oriol Yes and no - when you use inline - element will be hidden even when stylesheet fails to load (or have long delay), when you use stylesheet element will 'flash' before styles load.

I don't like inline styles and try to never use them, but this is one of short list of exceptions.

Also - if using stylesheets I prefer `.hidden` class, it won't mess with `display` property (you can always have table or other value there) and then you have fully separated styling from functionality.